# Visual Studio HTML editor curly bracket annoyance

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2008

Does any one know of a way to control how Visual Studio handles curly braces in Html view?

Type...

```
<% if (true) { %>
```

Then

```
<% { %>
```

And visual studio will auto format it as such.

```
<% if (true)
   { %>    
<% } %>
```

Not a major issue but nest a few of these using foreach and it gets messy.

Comment: When I type <% if (true) { %>

then 

<% } %>

it converts my code to be

<% if (true) 
{
%>
<% } %>

its just messy and annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its not really a sollution, but what i do is that i hit Ctrl+x to undo, and it will undo the formatting - there is not another way that i know off, other that changed it in all C# documents.

Comment: Sad that you can't set them individually

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  tools -> options -> texteditor -> JScript -> Formatting!

Comment: Not following gave this ago but JScript isnt going to effect ASPX pages (HTML)

Answer (score 0):

As the code is written in C#, it should be governed by the settings in tools | options | texteditor | c# | formatting.

Comment: So there is not a way to have 1 setting for ASPX pages and another for CS files?

Comment: Don't think so. In the next version of VS we will get html snippets that hopefully be customizable. If you use ReSharper, you might solve this using Live Templates.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1478453.aspx

there is also a 'formatting' section in the jscript node.  that was what my issue was.